# Wordpress divi site only works on first load

Tags: wordpress

I have been building a website and am  nearing completion, Everything was working fine, but suddenly it lost formatting and displayed all my modules inline,

after fiddling, ive found that after saving the website with out changes( saving from any page or location, them editor, divi builder, cpanel file editor), I can load the website and it loads and functions correctly... the first time, after the first load, once I refresh or visit on a different device, the problem re-appears..
no errors no warning... no idea :/

i have updated wordpress and all plugins, 
I have tried disabling possible problem modules, all to no avail, the issue persists across all pages..
Im stumped... is it a case of reinstallind worpress or divi... how would I safely do that ?? :O

thanks for your time :)

edit this is repeatable, everytime I hit save, the page loads correctly once.ad then on th second and subsequent attempts fails to load correctly.

first load,

section loads ad appears on top of the rest of the content (this is going to be an instructions video, but is now just a plain image), the close button hides the section , displaying the rest of the page behind..

[image][image]

once I hit refresh, the page loads like this
[image]

Same issue on the home page
first load
[image]

and then

[image]

these should give more information

```
element.style {
}
.et-l--post>.et_builder_inner_content>.et_pb_section {
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
}
.et_pb_section_0.et_pb_section {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)!important;
}
.et_pb_section_0 {
    max-height: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 981px)
.et_pb_section {
    padding: 0% 0;
}
@media (min-width: 981px)
.et_pb_section {
    padding: 4% 0;
}
.et_pb_section {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.et_pb_section, .et_pb_slider .et_pb_slide {
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

and second load

```
element.style {
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 981px)
.et_pb_section {
    padding: 0% 0;
}
@media (min-width: 981px)
.et_pb_section {
    padding: 4% 0;
}

.et_pb_section {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.et_pb_section, .et_pb_slider .et_pb_slide {
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Without specifics, we could only guess what the actual problem is, and might do more harm than help. If you could provide the URL, and if it is public, we could try and see how it renders..

Comment: www.vamooshrubbish.co.uk/services, I shall update it so it renders correctly when you first visit, you will see the issue once you refresh, thanks

Comment: The page loads the same content every time. Have you tried in an Incognito mode? Please add screenshots or examples of what EXACTLY is not loading for you the SECOND time? and what is expected EXACTLY to load, that is not ?

Comment: I have added screen shots to the main post thanks :)

Comment: From what I see, since the first load of the page on new browser I see what you show in your LAST image.. so it is either caching on your end, or simply this is how your page has been built. Why not start a new Service page from scratch? and add one element at a time, and clean test it, before adding next.. ? No need to reinstall WP or Divi

Comment: I have added some more photos that may help, the problem appear across both of my pages, and i have disabled all the modules, and I still have the issue,
cache isnt the issue as the problem appears across multiple devices (phone with different connection

first load works everytime regardless of device, and no go every other time regardless of whih device or switching in between, im fairly stump, it seems to be no pulling my custom formatting through in the css on the second load

Answer (score 0):

The minified file seems to be having parse errors: 
https://prnt.sc/s5vlev
https://prnt.sc/s5vlle

That file changes with each backend update/published page/post, etc.

And since it's added in the head, it loads before the content and the browser stops at that error and it doesn't load the style after it for the rest of the elements.

The file contains custom CSS you wrote in Custom CSS, Advanced tab, etc.

Try fixing the error and see if it helps or if you don't want any hassle, go to Divi => Theme Options and disable the Static CSS File Generation: http://prntscr.com/s5vox3

Make sure to test in Incognito afterwards.